# Test if VBAProject has protection via a macro from personal.xlsb

Tags: excel, vba

I create a handful of macros in my personal.xlsb to test other Excel tools. A macro should test if the VBAProject of the opened document has password protection.

I created the following code in my personal.xslb, which always shows True, no matter if I set a password for the test document or not.

```
Sub testVBAPasswort()
   '1 = VB-Project protected
   '0 = VB-Project not protected
    If Application.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.Protection = 1 Then
        MsgBox "False"
    Else
        MsgBox "True"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're running it on the `ActiveWorkbook` then the project will be unlocked. Try running it from an external workbook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try testing for an element of the `VBProject`. I do this with `Workbook.VBPRoject.VBComponents.Count`. Then I utilize an Error Handler to test for `Err.Number = 50289`, which means the workbook is password-protected and currently locked. Of course, once the `VBProject` is unlocked, it will no longer raise that error.

**Edit:**

You should directly reference the workbook you're trying to test, otherwise you're probably testing `personal.xlsb` itself. If you need to be able to dynamically test workbooks then just add

```
Dim w as Workbook
For each w in Application.Workbooks
    If Not w.Name = "personal.xlsb" Then
        If w.VBProject.Protection = 1 Then
            MsgBox w.Name & " Password Protected"
        Else
            MsgBox w.Name & " Not Password Protected"
        End If
    End If
Next w
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.

Comment: Glad to have helped!